# Save Format Dropdown Menu in FileDialog

Tags: java, filedialog

I'd like to create a Save dialog box in which the user can specify the file format to save a file in via a dropdown menu that appears below the name field. I'm using a FileDialog class rather than Swing's JFileChooser because it uses the native operating system's save dialog window, rather than a custom one (this is especially important on Mac OS X).

I've tried adding a FileNameFilter to the FileDialog box, but that seems to only affect it when it is in Load mode rather than Save mode. Is there any way to do this? And if not, are there any alternatives that preserve the native save dialog appearance?

Answer (score 0):

I used JFileChooser for a save dialog and used the UIManager to set the native look and feel for the system.

To add the format of the file I wanted to save, I just had to hardcode it into my application.

eg.  `out = new FileOutputStream(chooser.getSelectedFile() +".xls");`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, setting the UIManager to the Mac OS X look and feel does not provide an appearance that is anywhere close to a native Mac OS X save dialog, so that isn't going to work.